# tracker-extract high cpu usage

Tags: centos

I see that one of the users has a 100% cpu process named `tracker-extract`. I tried to terminate that based on the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51645277/859227), however, still I see that it is running. All users have such process but as you can see one of them consumes a lot of cpu.

```
# tracker daemon -t
Found 1 PID…
  Terminated process 2265 - 'tracker-server'
# ps aux | grep tracker-extract
jafarian 21478  0.0  0.0 728000 11664 ?        SNl  Oct29   0:00 /usr/libexec/tracker-extract
jafaria+ 23002 98.3  0.0 810900 18252 ?        RNl  Nov09 3746:02 /usr/libexec/tracker-extract
jafaria+ 31826  0.0  0.0 917128 21684 ?        SNl  Oct31   3:21 /usr/libexec/tracker-extract
```

Just killing the PID isn't a solution because it runs again. How to fix that?

Comment: Did you run the command in suggestion as root?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should install `tracker-ui-tools via yum`for older versions. For newer version install `tracker-preferences` directly.

Then use `tracker-preferences` to switch on/off what you want/don't want.

For more information check  [this link](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=53891#p227932) and
[this link.](http://www.putorius.net/2014/12/disable-tracker-on-fedora-21-fedora-20.html)

Comment: There is no such package. Is it fine to just install `tracker-preferences`?

Comment: yes, actually `tracker-ui-tools` is for older versions.

Comment: OK I installed that and then logged in as that user and ran `tracker-preferences` and unchecked the options. Still I see that a process for that user consumes 100% cpu.

Comment: Try to check after logout or restart. Is this one of the process which you check out??

Answer (score 0):

The processes are started with `.desktop` files in the `/etc/xdg/autostart` directory.

```bsh
[user@host autostart]$ pwd
 /etc/xdg/autostart

[user@host autostart]$ ls -lrt tracker*
 -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 5954 Sep 28 01:27 tracker-miner-fs.desktop
 -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 5234 Sep 28 01:27 tracker-miner-apps.desktop
 -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4635 Sep 28 01:27 tracker-miner-rss.desktop
 -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4880 Sep 28 01:27 tracker-extract.desktop
 -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 5474 Nov 12 08:02 tracker-store.desktop
```

So to disable `tracker` we will copy these files to our `~/.config/autostart` directory and add `Hidden=true`. This will stop them from loading when we log in.

```bsh
[user@host autostart]$ pwd
 /home/user/config/autostart

[user@host autostart]$ cp -v /etc/xdg/autostart/tracker* .
 '/etc/xdg/autostart/tracker-extract.desktop' -> './tracker-extract.desktop'
 '/etc/xdg/autostart/tracker-miner-apps.desktop' -> './tracker-miner-apps.desktop'
 '/etc/xdg/autostart/tracker-miner-fs.desktop' -> './tracker-miner-fs.desktop'
 '/etc/xdg/autostart/tracker-miner-rss.desktop' -> './tracker-miner-rss.desktop'
 '/etc/xdg/autostart/tracker-store.desktop' -> './tracker-store.desktop'

[user@host autostart]$ for FILE in $(ls tracker*); do echo "Hidden=true" >> $FILE; done
```

Now, let's kill the daemon, and delete the old cache files.

```
[user@host autostart]$ tracker daemon -k
[user@host autostart]$ rm -rf ~/.cache/tracker ~/.local/share/tracker
```

We should be good to go now. I did a reboot and IT IS GONE!

```
 !ps
 ps -ef | grep -i tracker
 root      2781  2748  0 17:27 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto -i tracker
```

Answer (score -1):

Centos 7

Please note:

Install tracker-preferences as root
yum install tracker-preferences

Run tracker-preferences as normal user
Set everything off (or leave whatever you think you need).

Reboot

System is nice again after that :))

Comment: And then it came back again.  Just when I posted my comment tracker-extract came back to live consuming 100% CPU. All I can think off is running tracker daemon -t after each boot. As a normal user. That seems to kill it.

Comment: And then it came back again.

Comment: I forgot to uncheck Enable for initial data population in tracker-preferences. It is ok now. Gone. I think. Because I saw tracker-extract pop up and die just now. k for me, I can always use tracker daemon -t if necessary. (For less experienced users something like this is enough to take the PC to a repair shop).

Comment: And now tracker-extract is back in full force, 100% CPU.

Comment: Last comment. I let the PC run for 2 days straight before and tracker-extract was still running. To me that looks abnormal. I have a lot of files but not that many. Also maybe an idea to use nice for tracker-extract so it does not stop you from using the system. Case closed.

Comment: Very last comment. See https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3364861 Redhat secret. Even with tracker disabled it all comes back to live again after a while.

Comment: Extreme measure for Die Hard. crontab -l * * * * * tracker daemon -t save Gone (crontab -l as user, not root)

Comment: crontab -e * * * * * tracker daemon -t Save (not crontab -l)

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Please make sure that the idea is working before posting. Thanks.

Comment: It is working fine Mahmood. Sorry for all the posts. Each time I thought I had the answer it looked good and I reported that. Then it came back again.